# Batch method to export DNN site templates

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

Is there a batch method to **export more than one DNN portal** in the same method as the 'Export Site Template' found under Host Settings > Site Management?

I'm having to manually export each website one-by-one and I was hoping there is a better method to do this.

I'm running **DNN Evoq Content 7.3.2**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  But ...

There is a new DNN Module named Prompt, which provides a command line interface for DNN administrative tasks.  It also is extensible and you can add additional commands to the Prompt module.  Last week's meeting of the Southern Fried DNN User Group included a presentation on extending the module by Kelly Ford himself.  If you google, you'll be able to find the recording of the presentation.  It was a fairly detailed presentation.

If you have a need for this capability on a continuing basis, it might be worth either developing this for yourself (and contributing it back to the community) or finding someone to do it for you.

(And the good news is that Prompt is expected to become part of the DNN core functionality later this year.  But, the current version of the module is available now.

Comment: thank you for the response. I will look into the Prompt module and see if it will fit our needs. I've generally been developing solutions to meet our DNN needs while also addressing security and accessibility concerns, so if I come around to developing a solution for this, I'll contribute it to the DNN community.

Comment: Highly suggest that you get in touch with Kelly.  You might "prompt" him to do something like that.

BTW, DNN 9.1 is advertised to have a new and greatly improved site import/export capability.

Comment: Thank you. We're in the midst of upgrading from version 7 to 9, but it's a slow process since we have many portals and three staging environments. Due to the upgrades we're performing, I've noticed the need I presented above and wanted to reach out to the community about this.